# Port 34037 is already in use Heroku + Nodejs + Express + WebSockets

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I tried everything I could find, but I can't get my deployment to work. I keep getting 'Application Error', although the app runs on my http://localserver:5000
Seems the problem is in bin/www

Here is the error log i get in Heroku. I suppose the issue is "**Port 34037 is already in use**"

```
pp[web.1]: > tubka@0.0.0 start /app
2015-02-04T09:29:03.327577+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2015-02-04T09:29:03.327578+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-02-04T09:29:03.695715+00:00 app[web.1]: http server listening on 34037
2015-02-04T09:29:03.761305+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2015-02-04T09:29:03.744365+00:00 app[web.1]: Port 34037 is already in use
2015-02-04T09:29:03.761400+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls tubka
2015-02-04T09:29:03.759922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! tubka@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2015-02-04T09:29:03.761610+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2015-02-04T09:29:03.760193+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2015-02-04T09:29:03.762242+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! command "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2015-02-04T09:29:03.760053+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2015-02-04T09:29:03.762111+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-40-generic
2015-02-04T09:29:03.760836+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the tubka package,
2015-02-04T09:29:03.762374+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! cwd /app
2015-02-04T09:29:03.760300+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the tubka@0.0.0 start script.
2015-02-04T09:29:03.762511+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
2015-02-04T09:29:03.760965+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2015-02-04T09:29:03.762654+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
2015-02-04T09:29:03.761073+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2015-02-04T09:29:03.762777+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2015-02-04T09:29:03.761194+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2015-02-04T09:29:03.766267+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
2015-02-04T09:29:03.766925+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not ok code 0
2015-02-04T09:29:03.766121+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2015-02-04T09:29:03.766678+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2015-02-04T09:29:03.718169+00:00 app[web.1]: websocket server created
2015-02-04T09:29:03.753343+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-02-04T09:29:04.473160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-02-04T09:29:04.482618+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-02-04T09:29:59.234120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tubka.herokuapp.com request_id=4edf0fd1-1231-440b-ac4a-4a21733e623f fwd="88.192.84.193" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-02-04T09:30:00.283732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tubka.herokuapp.com request_id=3fdcf81e-c40f-4770-ae0f-d83a7e672d1f fwd="88.192.84.193" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Internetz:gagtube alexandertazh$
```

I am following the [Heroku docs to deploy websockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets) with ws module.
Here is part of my app.js Nore the part **var port = process.env.PORT || 5000**

```
**var express = require('express')
var http = require("http");
var Crawler = require("simplecrawler");
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000
var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)
console.log("http server listening on %d", port)

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server})
console.log("websocket server created")

wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
    fs.readFile('./playlist.json', 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        ws.send(data);
        console.log(data);
    });
    console.log("websocket connection open")
    ws.on("close", function() {
    console.log("websocket connection close")
  })
})**
```

And client-side:

```
var host = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws')
var ws = new WebSocket(host);
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
playthelistclient.push(event.data);
};
```

My bin/www file part concerning ports:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the stuff related to ports in www file, because you already have that stuff in your app.js file:

```
//var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
//app.set('port', port);

//server.listen(port);
```